# Como rodar Shell Com PHP usando o compilador bash

Tags: php, bash, shell

Gostaria de saber como rodar *PHP* no *Shell*, utilizando o *Bash*. Tentei assim mas dar erro:

```
#/usr/bin/php
<?php
echo 'Olá Mundo';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

É necessário utilizar `#!` (com exclamação). Dessa forma você estará definindo o software que irá interpretar o código escrito, por exemplo: `#!/usr/bin/php`

No momento da execução é necessário verificar as permissões do arquivo. Para que o código seja executado, é necessário que o usuário tenha permissão de execução. Para verificar as permissões para utilizar `ls -l nome-do-arquivo.php`

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 45 May  3 02:56 ./nome-do-arquivo.php*
```

É necessário que tenha o `x`. Isso informa que o arquivo pode ser executado. Caso o `x` não apareça, basta executar o código abaixo.

```
sudo chmod +x nome-do-arquivo.php
```

**nome-do-arquivo.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    echo 'Olá Mundo';
?>
```

---

> /usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Caso você obtenha o erro acima, basta executar, no terminal, o seguinte código `which php`. Esse código irá retornar o caminho do interpretador do PHP, daí basta adicionar em `#!<caminho informado>`

Comment: eu acabo de fazer isso é da esse erro ./agente.php: /usr/bin/php: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: @HenriqueM Atualizei a resposta